# netbeans: takes 100% cpu when working with a big java project

Tags: cpu-usage, netbeans

Is there a way to debug what exactly causes netbeans to be so slow and to take so much resources? When I try to use code completion it takes around 20 to 30 seconds for the code completion to appear.

I moved to eclipse for now and it does not share the same problem./

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, you have a view which shows what is going on in the background. Netbeans has a little "activity" thingy in the status bar but it's either not used by everyone or there is other stuff going.

The first thing to try is to [give Netbeans 1GB of RAM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html). If that helps, you were hit by the garbage collector.

If that doesn't help, you can [send a signal](http://blogs.oracle.com/msreddy/entry/how_to_get_thread_dump) to the Java process to make it dump it's threads.

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention that I work on Intel i5 and Windows10-64bit.
I tried literally everything. After one of those system updates, my Netbeans 8.2 influenced a system to be very slow, almost to the point of unresponsiveness. During NB startup or build, system is practically unresponsive.
So, all possible tweaks both Netbeans and Java, couldn't solve a problem.
It seems that Windows update itself trigger off a problem to happen, as updates did changes on low system level, I suppose.
I decided to lower a Netbeans PID, by creating new shortcut like this :

```
cmd.exe /c start "Netbeans 8.2 LowPrio" /Low "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin\netbeans64.exe"
```

For now I can work without disruption, and it's far more smoother, than before.

https://github.com/dobrivoje/netbeansconfig

Answer (score 0):

I always had problems with Netbeans when coding but from I switched to Eclipse work has been much easier and compile time was in a jiff. Try out Eclipse and compare its performance with Netbeans.